# Use Arraylist as filter for OLEDB query

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, oledb

I'm using the below to populate an arraylist with the contents of a directory.

Is it possible to use the result of the arraylist as a filter of items to exclude from an OLEDB query? If not can someone point me in the direction of a better alternative - many thanks

```
  Dim NodeFile As New IO.DirectoryInfo(tempMail & tvProgress.SelectedNode.FullPath)
            Dim NodeList As IO.FileInfo() = NodeFile.GetFiles("*.*")
            Dim report As New ArrayList()
            For Each NodeExcl In NodeList
                report.Add(Path.GetFileName(NodeExcl.Name))
            Next
```

Query code

```
     Try

        Dim conn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Me.aClients & ""
        Dim n As Integer


        For n = 0 To UBound(AllDetails)
            Dim NodeFile As New IO.DirectoryInfo(tempMail & tvProgress.SelectedNode.FullPath)
            Dim NodeList As IO.FileInfo() = NodeFile.GetFiles("*.*")
            Dim report As New ArrayList()
            For Each NodeExcl In NodeList
                report.Add(Path.GetFileName(NodeExcl.Name))
            Next

            '' Need to exclude arraylist from query

            If tvProgress.Nodes.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

            If AllDetails(n).uName & " - " & AllDetails(n).uCode & " - " & AllDetails(n).uOps = e.Node.Text Then
                lstRequired.DataSource = Nothing
                lstRequired.DataBindings.Clear()

                Dim eSearch As String = AllDetails(n).uCode
                Dim fSearch As String = AllDetails(n).uOps

                da.SelectCommand.Connection.ConnectionString = conn
                da.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Documents.DocName FROM Documents WHERE (Documents.UnitCode = ?) AND (Documents.OpName = ?) AND Documents.Required = True ORDER BY DocName"
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", eSearch)
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", fSearch)
                da.Fill(dt)
                dt.Rows.Add("Add Additional Requirement")
                lstRequired.DataSource = dt
                lstRequired.DisplayMember = StrConv("DocName", VbStrConv.ProperCase)
                lstRequired.Refresh()

                Dim dl As DataTable = CType(lstRequired.DataSource, DataTable)
                Using sR = New IO.StreamReader(tFiles & UCase("ProgExcluded.txt"))
                    While (sR.Peek() > -1)
                        Dim rows() = dl.Select("DocName = '" + sR.ReadLine + "'")
                        For Each row In rows
                            row.Delete()
                        Next
                        dl.AcceptChanges()
                    End While
                End Using

            End If
        Next

        Exit Sub


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

I've had a bit of a think and now adapted some of the code to

```
            Dim NodeFile As New IO.DirectoryInfo(tempMail & tvProgress.SelectedNode.FullPath)
            Dim NodeList As IO.FileInfo() = NodeFile.GetFiles("*.*")
            Dim report As New ArrayList()

            For Each NodeExcl In NodeList
                report.Add(Path.GetFileName(NodeExcl.Name))
            Next
            Dim newreport As String = String.Join(",", report.ToArray())
```

with the idea of adding a multi string parameter in the where cause. Still trying to work out if that will work

Comment: Stop, why use an `ArrayList` for anything with Visual Studio 2012? Since .Net 2.0 you can use generics.

Comment: I've tried `List (of String)` as well....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cracked it..

Had to do a bit of concatenation with the string for the `WHERE` clause but it works a treat

```
Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("", "")
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim conn As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Me.aClients & ""
        Dim n As Integer


        For n = 0 To UBound(AllDetails)
            If AllDetails(n).uName & " - " & AllDetails(n).uCode & " - " & AllDetails(n).uOps = e.Node.Text Then

                Dim NodeFile As New IO.DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(tempMail, tvProgress.SelectedNode.FullPath))
                Dim reports = NodeFile.EnumerateFiles().Select(Function(f) Path.GetFileName(f.Name)).ToList()

                Dim newreport As String = String.Join("' AND Documents.DocName <> '", reports.ToArray())

                If tvProgress.Nodes.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

                Dim eSearch As String = AllDetails(n).uCode
                Dim fSearch As String = AllDetails(n).uOps
                Dim gsearch As String = "'" & newreport & "'"

                da.SelectCommand.Connection.ConnectionString = conn
                da.SelectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Documents.DocName FROM Documents WHERE (Documents.UnitCode = ?) AND (Documents.OpName = ?) AND (Documents.DocName <> " & gsearch & ") AND Documents.Required = True ORDER BY DocName"
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", eSearch)
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", fSearch)
                da.Fill(dt)

                dt.Rows.Add("Add Additional Requirement")
                lstRequired.DataSource = dt
                lstRequired.DisplayMember = "DocName"
                lstRequired.Refresh()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I take your first block of code and simplify it to

```
Dim NodeFile As New IO.DirectoryInfo( _
    Path.Combine(tempMail, tvProgress.SelectedNode.FullPath))
Dim reports = NodeFile.EnumerateFiles().Select(Function(f) _
    Path.GetFileName(f.Name)).ToList()
```

You'll see that reports is a `List(Of String)`. Welcome to the modern world.

---

If you need help to rewrite a swaith of legacy code please break it down into questions that will be useful to other people.

Comment: Thanks but I get the same effect as what I'd already written and it doesn't answer the question of which I'm asking of how to use it as a filter in an OLEDB query

Comment: @elmonko, so why include that code in the question. It just scares people off. Is your database Access?

Comment: @elmonko, there is so much wrong with the posted code, satellite to the actual question, its hard to continue.

Comment: The addition of the code is to show that I'm actually trying to work through this myself and this is what I've come up with so far. Yes, the database is an Access MDB and I'm simply trying to select all files from the column 'DocName' that alongside the the other `Where` clauses it also omits to return the documents  listed in the ArrayList/List of.